# Yii Embedding CHtml::listData into CGrid

Tags: yii

I'm trying to build a form that will enable the user to change values for multiple rows and then click submit. I am able to retrieve the rows from the database and display them in a table. However, instead of a textfield. I want to them to be droplists.

The `$list` contains options I want to display for each row's drop list.

What am I missing?

```
<div class="row bottom">
        <?php 
            $list = CHtml::listData(Attendancetype::model()->findAll(), 'AttendanceTypeID', 'AttendanceTypeName');    
            print_r($list);

            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>  $model->search(),
                'columns'=>array(
                'CalendarDate',
                'GradeName',
                array(
                'value'=>'$data->TeacherFirstName . " " . $data->TeacherLastname',
                'header'=>'Teacher'
            ),
                array(
                'value'=>'$data->FirstName . " " . $data->LastName',
                'header'=>'Student'
            ),
                array(
                'value'=>$list,
                'type'=>'raw',
                'header'=>'Status'
            ),

            ),

            ));

        ?>
    </div>
```

Current error message.

```
PHP warning

call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members

C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(611)

599      * @since 1.1.0
600      */
601     public function evaluateExpression($_expression_,$_data_=array())
602     {
603         if(is_string($_expression_))
604         {
605             extract($_data_);
606             return eval('return '.$_expression_.';');
607         }
608         else
609         {
610             $_data_[]=$this;
611             return call_user_func_array($_expression_, $_data_);
612         }
613     }
614 }
615 
616
```

Comment: Yii error messages normally have a call stack. Any chance you could narrow down the error message to a line in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this in your cgridview

```
 array('header'=>'Action',
     'type'=>'raw',
     'value'=>"CHtml::dropDownlist('actionList','', CHtml::listData(
            Attendancetype::model()->findAll(), 'AttendanceTypeID', 'AttendanceTypeName'),array())"
       ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to previous answer. If you want to use external variable you need to define it in your CColumn.
So your code will look like:

```
$list = CHtml::listData(Attendancetype::model()->findAll(), 'AttendanceTypeID', 'AttendanceTypeName');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'dataProvider'=>  $model->search(),
                'columns'=>array(
....
array('header'=>'Action',
     'type'=>'raw',
     'value'=> function ($data,$row) use $list {return CHtml::dropDownlist('actionList','', $list,array());}
       ),
```

This will work like you need. Same with Ninad answer.
Cgridview is most flexible yii widget and have alot of wiki examples.